# Name two portions of a string as variables with Powershell

Tags: powershell

helpful Stack Overflow community,

I am working with automated report-outs (`.txt` docs) that contain two pieces of info I need in a larger string. I need to find a way to create variables from each of these and use them to pipe into another command.

Example of Report-Out:

```
B072L8FX9H  2017-11-17 14:49:17 -05:00  2017-11-17 14:49:17 -05:00  D1  volenick    amandun                     -   -
```

I need to create two variables, one containing the first bit of text, the file name `B072L8FX9H` and one variable containing the last bit, the username `amandun`.

Please note the filename will always be 10 digits, but the username length will vary. Additionally, the spaces at the end prior to the `-   -` vary. These inconsistencies make me wary of utilizing trim but I am not opposed.

assuming I can get these two variables I believe I can then pipe them into a `foreach` statement to tag the actual files

Additional examples of Report-Out:

```
B075XR6ZR1  2017-11-17 15:19:22 -05:00  2017-11-17 15:19:22 -05:00  D1  volenick    pascalec                        -   -

B01C5AVSBW  2017-11-17 15:21:40 -05:00  2017-11-17 15:21:40 -05:00  D1  volenick    Gunthorp                        -   -

B076FHS4CZ  2017-11-17 15:23:36 -05:00  2017-11-17 15:23:36 -05:00  D1  volenick    amandun                     -   -
```

I havent been able to build a trim command that works with all the inconsistencies. Perhaps there is a better way to extract these variables.

Thanks

EDIT - This is the solution we ended up using:

```
#generate individual file to user relationships
$dailyuserSheet = report.txt
$a=@()
$row = ""|Select file, user
$a +=$row
Foreach ($line in(Get-Content $dailyuserSheet)){
If($line -ne ""){
$file = $line.split("`t")[0]
$user = $line.split("`t")[5]
$a += "$file `t $user"
}
}
```

Comment: I suspect folks are down-voting this question for a perceived lack of effort to solve it yourself.  You mentioned that you'd tried variations on trim - elaborating on what you tried may address the concerns.  That said, I could imagine what you might have tried and knew Trim is the wrong tool for this particular job - so you weren't going to be able to solve it.  You gave good usable examples of your inputs, and clear definition of what you were trying to get out.  Personally, I'm okay with the question.

Comment: Thank Matt, I agree. I've added the bit that we ended up going with. Thanks again for everyone's help.

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer - perhaps one that is closest to your solution.  That will prevent people from revisiting the question to try answering it.

Answer (score 1):

This is ***a*** way to retrieve the information you want.

```
$Parse = 'B072L8FX9H  2017-11-17 14:49:17 -05:00  2017-11-17 14:49:17 -05:00  D1  volenick    amandun                     -   -   '
$Parse = $Parse.Trim()

$Parse -match '\w+\s+-\s+-$' >$Null #returns $True

$Username = $Matches[0] -replace '\s+-\s+-'
$FileName = ($Parse -split '\s')[0]
```

Comment: I started with straight up matches for the desired fields, too, but figured the very next thing to get asked was "How do I get the time, too?"  Good answer, though.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way, that will split all the fields out.

```
$test = @"
B075XR6ZR1  2017-11-17 15:19:22 -05:00  2017-11-17 15:19:22 -05:00  D1  volenick    pascalec                        -   -
B075XR6ZR1  2017-11-17 15:19:22 -05:00  2017-11-17 15:19:22 -05:00  D1  volenick    pascalec                        -   -
B01C5AVSBW  2017-11-17 15:21:40 -05:00  2017-11-17 15:21:40 -05:00  D1  volenick    Gunthorp                        -   -
B076FHS4CZ  2017-11-17 15:23:36 -05:00  2017-11-17 15:23:36 -05:00  D1  volenick    amandun                     -   -
"@

# Depending on how you take your input, splitting the lines can be more straight forward.  
# This just splits lines by the -   - at the end of each line, ignoring how 
# much whitespace is at the end of the line.  
# Get-Content from a file would automatically split the lines.
$lines = $test -split "-\s*-\s*"

foreach($line in $lines)
{
    # split each field of the data based on contiguous whitespace.  
    # this will fail if you have whitespace in a name or file, for example.
    $fields = $line -split "\s+"
    Write-Output "$($fields[0]) $($fields[9])"
}
```

With the output:

> ```
> B075XR6ZR1 pascalec
> B075XR6ZR1 pascalec
> B01C5AVSBW Gunthorp
> B076FHS4CZ amandun
> ```